# Disabling auto-hiding of vertical scrollbar in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, scrollbar

I'm wondering whether there is any option/control to disable the automatic hiding (fade-out effect) of vertical scrollbar that happens after few seconds of mouse inactivity in Microsoft Word 2013?

I couldn't find an option/solution on this.

**NOTE:** I also have the option '***Show vertical scroll bar***' checked under ***File > Options > Advanced > Display***.

Comment: I was trying to look for a way to disable this too. I've tried disabling hardware acceleration in Office, and I've also tried disabling window control animations from Windows itself. All that does is make the scrollbar disappear instead of fade out. Looks like we're out of luck unless someone can find a registry hack.

Comment: Excellent question. I don't want objects flashing in and out of visibility when I move the mouse around. If I want something hidden, I will minimize the window!

Comment: Whoever came up with that idea should be fired. **This is why there are multiple viewing modes in Word,** dumb developers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a hack that stops the scrollbar from disappearing, though I'm not sure whether Microsoft considers it a bug or a feature:

1. Go into "VIEW | Read Mode".
2. Select "VIEW | Layout | Paper Layout".
3. Press Escape to get back into Print Layout, and then the scrollbar shouldn't disappear.

To do this more quickly, get used to typing:

1. Alt-W-F
2. Alt-W-L-P
3. Esc

Comment: Wow !!! That solves the very long inconvenience that was bothering me for sometime. As you had also indicated, I too guess that it should be a bug, however that indirectly solves this issue here.

Comment: Any solution for Word 2016? There is no "File; Read mode" here.

Comment: @ygoe _Read Mode_ option is available under 'View' menu in Word 2016.  Or, you can find this in the bottom right status bar, which is the first symbol that looks like a book.

Comment: Works in Word 2016, but the fix is not permanent. The scrollbar begins to disappear again after restarting Word.

Comment: @ygoe Yes, you're right.  This is not a permanent fix, this comes as a handy workaround in my case though.

Comment: In Word 2013, the "Read mode" option is not in the FILE menu, but on the VIEW ribbon. Consider editing the answer.

Comment: FYI, the problem is still present in Word 2019 and this fix also still works.

Comment: I use this workaround daily several times, great there is this workaround, but it should be a setting. The auto-hiding is an annoying 'feature' that neccesitates extra clicks. I hope MS adds a setting for this in an update. I don't use Word for its prettieness but to get work done...

Answer (score 6):

[Jez’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1107136/150988) is good, but it is rather annoying that you have to do this every time you start Word, so I just made a macro (by recording the keystrokes) and then put the macro on the <kbd>Home</kbd> tab of the Ribbon.

Here's the macro:

```vb
Sub Fix_Scrollbar()
'
' Fix_Scrollbar Macro
'
'
    ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = Not ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout
    Selection.EscapeKey
    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    Else
        ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
End Sub
```

So now it’s just one click when Word starts ...

Comment: If you call this function in the documents Open or New Events, then this will run every time you have a document open.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there it's no solution for your problem at the moment:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-vertical-scrollbar-auto-hiding-in-print/2656ff19-ebc6-4f3f-8611-121bfd4072ab?page=1&tm=1434983755116

I disabled the animations (smooth movements) in all the Office 2013 and I have the same auto-hiding of the scrollbar you're refering.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution, but it's the solution I prefer because my vertical scrollbar now stays where I can see it at all times.  Go to the "View" tab at the top of the screen.  Go to the "Views" section on the left.  On the right side of that box, click "Draft".  It resizes your window to "text width" basically and disallows the scrollbar from vanishing while pausing / typing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When comparing documents, the "Read Mode" suggested in other answers is not available (at least in Word 2013), so this is a good solution for that case.